# What verb can I use instead of "get" in "which company should get the contract"?

Tags: word-choice, formal-language

As the heading suggests, I'm looking for an alternative to "get" in the sentence "Which company should get the contract". I guess "get" works, but I would like a more formal word (if there is one). Can I use "obtain" in this context? Or something else?

Comment: "Win the contract" is possible, as an elision of the more correct "win *the bid for* the contract."

Comment: @randomhead Yes, I thought of that as well, but I thought that would be even more informal?

Comment: Which should receive the contract; which should be awarded the contract. Informal? Which should walk away with the contract.

Comment: Anecdotally, I believe that the "most formal" wording would be ***...should be awarded the contract.***.

Comment: Yes – *awarded* makes perfect sense! Thank you both!

Comment: I agree, "awarded" is good. Note the difference between active and passive, though... the bidder *gets* or *wins* the contract (active) or *is awarded* the contract (passive). Do you want to emphasize the work the contractor did in preparing their bid, or emphasize the work the overlying agency did in evaluating all the bids?

Comment: @randomhead Good point! It should be construed from the point of view of the evaluating agency, so *award* is a good fit :)